# Selection of lines from a multiple condition request

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, where-clause

I have a MySQL table named "proposition" with the primary key "idProposition" and an other table named "needs" with columns "idProposition" and "idRequirement". I'd want to get the propositions which linked requirements are all in the $requireList php array.

I tried to do like that:

```
$req = "SELECT idProposition FROM proposition
        WHERE (SELECT idProposition FROM proposition
                 WHERE needs.idProposition = proposition.idProposition
                       AND idRequirement NOT IN($requireList))
          IS NULL";
```

But when I make the request, I have the following error:

```
#1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row
```

Meaning that it can't test if the result (propositions having needs not in $requireList) is null because there are several results.
How could I test if the internal SELECT provides result?

Thanks for you help.

Comment: why not just LIMIT 1?, or use JOINS.

Comment: There is no table `needs` in the `FROM` clauses of your query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM proposition p
  INNER JOIN needs n ON n.idProposition = p.idProposition
WHERE idRequirement IN (1, 7, 9)    # blah, blah, blah, put your list here
GROUP BY p.idProposition
HAVING COUNT(idRequirement) = 3     # put the size of the list here
```

What it does: it `SELECT`s all the propositions together that are liked with requirements from the list. It doesn't matter if only one requirement is linked or all of them. Then it `GROUP`s those rows `BY` propositions. Each proposition will produce a single row of data. Then it keeps from these rows only those `HAVING` the same number of requirements as the size of your list (i.e. all the requirements are present).

I didn't test it but it should work. If it doesn't, just add `COUNT(idRequirement)` to the `SELECT` clause.

Comment: Doesn't work because for example, a proposition without requirement won't be detected whereas all its requirements are in the list.

Comment: I found a quite dirty but working solution based on yours: I added in the data base the requirement 0 for all the propositions. $requireList never contains 0. And I used "HAVING COUNT(idRequirement)=1" so that only the unreachable condition remain.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
SELECT idProposition FROM proposition 
INNER JOIN needs on proposition.idProposition = needs.idproposition
```

instead of

```
SELECT idProposition FROM proposition
        WHERE (SELECT idProposition FROM proposition
                 WHERE needs.idProposition = proposition.idProposition
```